# AJAX call like Facebook

Tags: ajax, facebook

I want to create a little social network (a little test).
How can Ii implement periodical ajax call like Facebook?
I need to update news, status, ...
How does Facebook do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setTimeOut](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) and [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) in javascript to time ajax calls.

EDIT:

If there are no changes you can use a larger time before for the next interval. This is sometimes called Exponential Backoff.

Comment: I know this solution, but is it the only way ?
Because if there are no changes i got overhead, no ?

Comment: Why don't you try some AjAX framework which will handle all background complexity. May be DWR

Answer (score 0):

A technique called "Comet push", which can perform real-time server information push, may suit your need.
As far as I know, it can be implemented in Ruby(Dojo) and ASP.NET (handlers).
The "chat" function of Facebook uses Comet-like architecture.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29